# Python CGI scripts not running / pulling form data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty new to python and totally new to stack overflow :)

I have a problem & am hoping you can advise.

Below, I have a snippet of my HTML form. It calls my file backend.py (the script for which is a bit lower).

For some reason, I run the script & it doesn't produce the file & doesn't print the variable. I don't have SSH access as I'm using a shared host and I don't really know how I can troubleshoot the script / see logs. Can anyone advise?

If there is anything I'm doing that's obviously wrong, please let me know. I don't think it's picking up the variables from the form. If I hardcode the variables locally, it runs, so there is no issue with the actual script, but maybe with the CGI bit.

The py script does print the HTML code!

```
<form action="../cgi-bin/backend.py" method="post" multipart id="form" class="tab-wizard wizard-circle">
        <h6><font color="#2eb9f7">Data Source Info</font></h6>
        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="origindatabase">Hive Database Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="origindatabase"> </div>
                    </div>
```

backend.cgi includes the below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import cgi
import sys

def getData():
    formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
    database = formData.getvalue('database')
    table = formData.getvalue('origintable')
    select_fields = formData.getvalue('select')
    aggrequired = formData.getvalue('aggrequired')
    aggtype = formData.getvalue('aggtype')
    aggfield = formData.getvalue('aggfield')
    aggalias = formData.getvalue('aggalias')
    agg2required = formData.getvalue('agg2required')
    aggtype2 = formData.getvalue('agg2type')
    aggfield2= formData.getvalue('agg2field')
    aggalias2 = formData.getvalue('agg2alias')
    grouprequired = formData.getvalue('group')
    group_fields = formData.getvalue('group_fields')
    selectfields = formData.getvalue('finalselect')
    hivesavedb = formData.getvalue('destinationdb')
    hivesavetable = formData.getvalue('destinationtable')
    whererequired = formData.getvalue('whererequired')
    where1field = formData.getvalue('where1field')
    where1operator = formData.getvalue('where1operator')
    where1criteria = formData.getvalue('where1criteria')
    where2required = formData.getvalue('where2')
    where2type = formData.getvalue('typeofwhere')
    where2field = formData.getvalue('where2field')
    where2operator = formData.getvalue('where2operator')
    where2criteria = formData.getvalue('where2criteria')
    joinrequired = formData.getvalue('joinrequired')
    jointable = formData.getvalue('jointable')
    joinfield1 = formData.getvalue('joinfield1')
    joinfield2 = formData.getvalue('joinfield2')
    joinlocation = formData.getvalue('whenjoin')
    join_field_selection = formData.getvalue('where2criteria')

    return database
    return table
    return select_fields
    return aggrequired
    return aggtype
    return aggfield
    return aggalias
    return agg2required
    return aggtype2
    return aggfield2
    return aggalias2
    return grouprequired
    return group_fields
    return selectfields
    return hivesavedb
    return hivesavetable
    return whererequired
    return where1field
    return where1operator
    return where1criteria
    return where2required
    return where2type
    return where2field
    return where2operator
    return where2criteria
    return joinrequired
    return jointable
    return joinfield1
    return joinfield2
    return joinlocation
    return join_field_selection

def index():    
    try:
        database = getData()
        table = getData()
        select_fields = getData()
        aggrequired = getData()
        aggtype = getData()
        aggfield = getData()
        aggalias = getData()
        agg2required = getData()
        aggtype2 = getData()
        aggfield2 = getData()
        aggalias2 = getData()
        grouprequired = getData()
        group_fields = getData()
        selectfields = getData()
        hivesavedb = getData()
        hivesavetable = getData()
        whererequired = getData()
        where1field = getData()
        where1operator = getData()
        where1criteria = getData()
        where2required = getData()
        where2type = getData()
        where2field = getData()
        where2operator = getData()
        where2criteria = getData()
        joinrequired = getData()
        jointable = getData()
        joinfield1 = getData()
        joinfield2 = getData()
        joinlocation = getData()
        join_field_selection = getData()

        file = open("testfile1.txt","a")
        #LIBRARY IMPORTS#
        file.write('from pyspark.sql import SparkSession\nimport argparse, sys\nimport pyspark.sql.functions as sqlfunc\nfrom pyspark.sql import *\nfrom pyspark.sql.functions import *\nfrom datetime import datetime\n')
        #CREATE SPARK SESSION#
        file.write('def create_session(appname):\n')
        file.write('\tspark_session = SparkSession\n')
        file.write('.builder\n')
        file.write('.appName(appname)\n')
        file.write('.master(\'yarn\')\n')
        file.write('.config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://uds-far1-mn1.dab.o2.net:9083")\n')
        file.write('.enableHiveSupport()\n')
        file.write('.getOrCreate()\n')
        file.write('\treturn spark_session\n')

        #MAIN CLASS#
        file.write('if __name__ == \'__main__\':\n')
        file.write('\tspark_session = create_session(\'roamingdata\')\n')
        print("opened main class")

        #CREATE DF1 / DF2 FROM DB#
        file.write('\tdf = spark_session.table(\'' + database + '.' + table + '\')\n')
        if joinrequired == 'YES' or joinrequired == 'yes' or joinrequired == 'Yes':
            file.write('\tdf2 = spark_session.table(\'' + database2 + '.' + table2 + '\')\n')
        print("created dataframes")

        #DF1 FILTERS AND OPTIONS#                
        file.write('\tfiltereddf = df.coalesce(1000)')
        if whererequired == 'YES' and where2required == 'NO':
            file.write('.filter((df.' + where1field + where1operator + where1criteria + '))')
        if whererequired == 'YES' and where2required == 'YES':
            file.write('.filter((df.[' + where1field + ']' + where1operator + where1criteria + ')'+ where2type + '(df.[' + where2field + ']' + where2operator + where2criteria + '))')
        file.write('.select('+ select_fields+')')
        print("applied dataframe1 filters")

        #DF2 FILTERS AND OPTIONS#
        if joinrequired == 'YES' or joinrequired == 'yes' or joinrequired == 'Yes':
            file.write('\tfiltereddf2 = df2.coalesce(1000)')
            if df2whererequired == 'YES' and df2whererequired == 'NO':
                file.write('.filter((df2.' + df2where1field + df2where1operator + df2where1criteria + '))')
            if df2whererequired == 'YES' and df2where2required == 'YES':
                file.write('.filter((df2.[' + df2where1field + ']' + df2where1operator + df2where1criteria + ')'+ df2where2type + '(df2.[' + df2where2field + ']' + df2where2operator + df2where2criteria + '))')
            file.write('.select('+ select_fields+')')
        file.write('finaldf = filtereddf')
        print("applied dataframe2 filters")

        if joinrequired == 'YES' or joinrequired == 'yes' or joinrequired == 'Yes':
            file.write('.join(filtereddf2 , filtereddf.'+ joinfield1 + '== filtereddf2.' + joinfield2 + ')')
        print("joined dataframes")

        file.write('.select('+ join_field_selection+')')
        file.write('.groupBy('+ group_fields + ')')

        if aggrequired == 'YES' or aggrequired == 'yes' or aggrequired == 'Yes':
            file.write('.agg(sqlfunc.'+aggtype+'(df.'+ aggfield+').alias(\''+aggalias+'\')')
            if agg2required == 'YES' or agg2required == 'yes' or agg2required == 'Yes':
                file.write(',sqlfunc.'+aggtype2+'(df.'+ aggfield2+').alias(\''+aggalias2+'\'))')

        file.write('.select('+selectfields+')\n')
        print("did aggregations on joined dataframes")

        file.write('df_agg.createOrReplaceTempView("temporarytable")\n')
        file.write('finaldf = spark_session.sql("INSERT INTO table ' + hivesavedb + '.' + hivesavetable + ' select * from temporarytable")');
        file.close()

    except:
        print('no')
print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print ('<html>')
print ('<head>')
print ('<title>Response </title>')
print ('</head>')
print ('<body>')
print ('<h2>Hello.</h2>')
print ('</body>')
print ('</html')
```

Comment: 1. Does your hosting support running python/python3 scripts?  
2. Why your script has `.cgi` extension instead of `.py`?
3. Does running simple `print ('Hello word!')` script produce any output?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, the host supports running python3 scripts. I have changed the extension to .py and have the same issue. The HTML within the py file does appear on the screen.  However, I'm not getting any of the desired output (the txt file).

Comment: I'd guess you have to use `sys.stdout.write('output text')` (and `import sys` beforehand) instead of using `print()`. But please try to avoid using cgi in general - it's deprecated. Try to use wsgi instead, if the hosting supports it (I bet it does)